# How to connect xib file to an header file in objective c

Tags: objective-c, customization, uialertview

i have a custom uialertview created in interface builder with an uitextfield and two uibutton.
I've created an header file like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DialogWelcome : UIAlertView{
    UITextField *text;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *text; 
- (IBAction)ok;
- (IBAction)annulla;

@end
```

in interface builder i find the two method IBAction and i can connect with uibutton, but i don't find text. I set the file owner's custom class with name of .m and .h. What can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable needs to be declared as an `IBOutlet`:

`IBOutlet UITextField * text`